# Different type for a specific field in Elasticsearch Mapping

Tags: database, elasticsearch, mapping

I have a field that its value type changes. For example, one data (doc) has name as a keyword

```
"user_information": [
 {
     "name": "Mike",
     "age": 3
    }
  }
  ]
```

I have another data (doc) that has name as a JSON.

```
"user_information": [
   {
       "name": {
        "first_name": "Joe",
        "last_name": "Doe"
       },
       "age": 3
      }
    }
    ]
```

How can I do elasticsearch mapping for this?

```
 "name": {
            "dynamic": true,
            "type": "keyword"
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you already have a field with a defined type. Probably you should be getting the error below when trying to index the two documents.

> object mapping for [user_information.name] tried to parse field [name]
> as object, but found a concrete value"

Comment: You should still be able to index it but not make it search